# Logging using Azure BlockBlob (Writing into text files using multiple writer scenarios)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to use a "classical" log-approach writing lines of text into a text file. Instead of saving this locally I want to write the data into a blockblob. This is the code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer share = blobClient.GetContainerReference("logStorage");
var logFile=share.GetAppendBlobReference("mylog.log");
logFile.AppendText("This is a log entry");
```

This works, but only in single-writer scenarios as the documenation clearly states for AppendText():

> This API should be used strictly in a single writer scenario because
>   the API internally uses the append-offset conditional header to avoid
>   duplicate blocks which does not work in a multiple writer scenario.

So if I need that functionality in **multiple writer** scenarios what do I have to use as an alternative?

Comment: have you tried log4net plugin for azure storage . it is quite simple to setup https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure . You can always have simple wrapper class that returns a singleton log4net object.

Comment: I know that appender. They get around the problem by storing each log-entry into a seperate File. Not really a smart solution for that problem. Also: That is xml not plan text

Comment: oh yeah.. or you can try having a separate service that watches the log folder on your machine and it can upload the files as and when there is one. whereas the main task/ thread will simply create logs in a folder. and the uploader will take care of upload. in the uploader you can see if you can use TPL to start off as many tasks for as many files to be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not what this is about. If MSDN clearly states that this method should not be used in multiple writer scenarios there should be one that does. Also: This might be interesting in other scenarios and not just for logging.

Comment: Did you try SLAB with Azure Table Storage ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775011(v=pandp.20).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OleAlbers, as @TamraMyers-Microsoft said, the description below from the section "Avoiding duplicate or delayed appends" of REST API [`Append Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt427365.aspx), it's a way for the multi-writer scenario.

> In a multiple writer scenario, each client can use conditional headers, but this may not be an optimal approach in terms of performance.

But the reference also said as below.

> For the highest concurrent append throughput, applications should handle redundant appends and delayed appends in their application layer (e.g., add epochs or sequence numbers in the data being appended).

I think the simple & best way to satisfy your needs is using a lock-free solution, such as the new [Dataflow library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx), part of the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async), to asyncly perform the multi-writer operations.

You can try to refer to the tutorial [`How to: Write Messages to and Read Messages from a Dataflow Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228597(v=vs.110).aspx) to rewrite your single-writer code to be suitable for the multi-writer scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For the multi-writer scenario, call [Append Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt427365.aspx) instead of AppendText. See the [AppendBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudappendblob.appendblock.aspx) method in the client library.

Append Block provides atomicity but limits the payload to the size of a single block.